# Why energy eigenstates are extrema of the energy functional?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hamiltonian, variational-principle, eigenvalue

We have the energy functional of a system:

$$E[\psi] = \frac{\langle \psi | \hat{H} | \psi \rangle}{\langle \psi | \psi \rangle}$$

and over numerous textbooks it is said that the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian $\left(\hat{H}| \psi \rangle = E| \psi \rangle\right)$ are also extrema of the energy functional so that

$$\hat{H}| \psi \rangle = E| \psi \rangle$$

and

$$\frac{\delta E[\psi]}{\delta\psi} = 0$$

are equivalent statements.

I can see that it is so for the ground state since it will be the minimum of the energy functional, but I can't see why it is also true for excited states.

Comment: Please give a reference.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/776490/why-does-the-variational-method-simplify-in-this-way-when-h-hermitian) contains the answer to your question, I think.

Comment: As a reference, Density-Functional Theory of Atoms and Molecules by Parr and Yang, 
Here is the statement:

"Every eigenstate $\psi$ is an extremum of the functional $E[\psi]$. In other
words, one may replace the Schrodinger equation (1.1.1) with the
variational principle
When (1.2.7) is satisfied, so is (1.1.1), and vice versa."
Here (1.1.1) is $\hat{H}|\psi = E\psi$
and (1.2.7) is $\delta E[\psi] = 0$ with energy functional defined as I did above.

Comment: @TobiasFünke the same question answered within 24 hours!

Comment: It did :) Thanks a lot!